# Python: Add a new line after the first word in a sentence if the first word is all caps

Tags: python

I'm trying to modify a txt file. The file is a movie script in the format:

```
BEN We’ve discussed this before.
LUKE I can be a Jedi. I’m ready.
```

I'd like insert a new line after the character:

```
BEN 
We’ve discussed this before.
LUKE 
I can be a Jedi. I’m ready.
```

How do I do this in python? I currently have:

```
def modify_file(file_name):
  fh=fileinput.input(file_name,inplace=True)
  for line in fh:
    split_line = line.split()
    if(len(split_line)>0):
      first_word = split_line[0]
      replacement = first_word+'\n'
      first_word=first_word.replace(first_word,replacement)
      sys.stdout.write(first_word)
      fh.close()
```

Comment: `string.split()` + `words.isupper()` would be the answer ... but, what've you tried?

Comment: If the text is big, **regular expressions** are the way to go `import re`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments, this can be done using `split` and `isupper`. An example is provided below:

```
source_path = 'source_path.txt'

f = open(source_path)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

temp = ''
for line in lines:
    words = line.split(' ')
    if words[0].isupper():
        temp += words[0] + '\n' + ' '.join(words[1:])
    else:
        temp += line

f = open(source_path, 'w')
f.write(temp)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

```
import fileinput
def modify_file(file_name):
    fh=fileinput.input("output.txt",inplace=True)
    for line in fh:
        split_line = line.split()
            if(len(split_line)>0):
                x=split_line[0]+"\n"+" ".join(split_line[1:])+"\n"
                sys.stdout.write(x)

    fh.close()  #==>this cannot be in the if loop.It has to be at the outer for level
```